# Need assistance drawing line segments using arrow keys

Tags: java, javafx

Now all I get are the dots, but with no lines connecting them....
Should I be re-creating the original "line" that is initialized before my switch? Or should I not be creating new lines at all but rather re-modifying the original line?

```
public class DrawLineWithArrowKeys extends Application {
    double bX = 150;
    double bY = 150;
    double eX = 150;
    double eY = 150;
    double segment = 20;
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
Pane myPane = new Pane();

Line line = new Line(bX,bY,eX,eY);
line.setStrokeWidth(2);
line.setStroke(Color.RED);
myPane.getChildren().add(line);

line.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
 if (e.getCode().isArrowKey())
 {
    switch (e.getCode()) {

    case DOWN:
        bY += segment;
        eY = bY;
        Line line2 = new Line(bX,bY,eX,eY);
        line2.setStrokeWidth(2);
        line2.setStroke(Color.GREEN);
        myPane.getChildren().add(line2);
        break;

    case UP:
        bY -= segment;
        eY = bY;
        Line line3 = new Line(bX,bY,eX,eY);
        line3.setStrokeWidth(2);
        line3.setStroke(Color.GREEN);
        myPane.getChildren().add(line3);
        break;

    case LEFT: 
        bX -= segment;
        eX = bX;
        Line line4 = new Line(bX,bY, eX, eY);
        line4.setStrokeWidth(2);
        line4.setStroke(Color.GREEN);
        myPane.getChildren().add(line4);
        break;

    case RIGHT: 
        bX += segment;
        eX = bX;
        Line line5 = new Line(bX,bY,eX,eY);
        line5.setStrokeWidth(2);
        line5.setStroke(Color.GREEN);
        myPane.getChildren().add(line5);
        break;

        default: 



        break;
    }
 }
});


Scene scene = new Scene(myPane, 300, 300);
primaryStage.setTitle("Draw Line with Arrow Keys");
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();
line.requestFocus();
```

}

Comment: @Uluk Biy, modified code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured it out, thank you for not just handing the answer to me, but I did end up stepping through your code and breaking it down to see how it worked... As a result, I was able to come up with a solution to the assignment...

```
package skowronek15;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;



public class DrawLineWithArrowKeys extends Application {
double bX = 150; //start x value denote for beginning-X
double bY = 150; //start y value denote for beginning-y
double eX = 150; //start x value denote for end-x
double eY = 150; //start y value denote for end-y
double bX2, bY2; //start of next line
double segment = 20; //length of segment


@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Pane myPane = new Pane(); //create a pane


    Line line = new Line(bX,bY,eX,eY); //create the starting or initial line
    line.setStrokeWidth(2); //set width
    line.setStroke(Color.RED); //set color
    myPane.getChildren().add(line); //add line to pane

    line.setOnKeyPressed(e -> { //switch statement to determine what happens when
                                // each key is pressed
     if (e.getCode().isArrowKey())
     {
        switch (e.getCode()) {

        case DOWN:
            bY2 = bY ; //start of next line, bY2 is equal to the start of originating
                       // y-coordinate bY
            bY += segment;//increment start of first line
            eY = bY; // end y (eY) coordinate equal to beginning y coordinate (bY) after 
                    // it's incremented;


            Line line2 = new Line(bX,bY2,eX,eY); //create a new line to be drawn;
                                //beginning y coordinate is now bY2;
            line2.setStrokeWidth(2);
            line2.setStroke(Color.GREEN);
            myPane.getChildren().add(line2);
            break;

        case UP:
            bY2 = bY;
            bY -= segment;
            eY = bY;

            Line line3 = new Line(bX,bY2,eX,eY);
            line3.setStrokeWidth(2);
            line3.setStroke(Color.GREEN);
            myPane.getChildren().add(line3);
            break;

        case LEFT:
            bX2 = bX;
            bX -= segment;
            eX = bX;

            Line line4 = new Line(bX2,bY, eX, eY);
            line4.setStrokeWidth(2);
            line4.setStroke(Color.GREEN);
            myPane.getChildren().add(line4);
            break;

        case RIGHT: 
            bX2 = bX;
            bX += segment;
            eX = bX;
            Line line5 = new Line(bX2,bY,eX,eY);
            line5.setStrokeWidth(2);
            line5.setStroke(Color.GREEN);
            myPane.getChildren().add(line5);
            line5.getStrokeLineJoin();
            break;

            default:


            break;
        }
     }
    });


    Scene scene = new Scene(myPane, 300, 300);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Draw Line with Arrow Keys");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
    line.requestFocus();



}






public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Path` with its `PathElement`s:

```
private int bX = 75, bY = 75;
private int step = 20;


@Override
public void start( Stage primaryStage )
{

    Pane myPane = new Pane();
    Path path = new Path( new MoveTo( bX, bY ) ); // move to starting point
    path.setStrokeWidth( 1 );
    path.setStroke( Color.GREEN );

    myPane.getChildren().add( path );

    path.setOnKeyPressed( e ->
    {
        if ( e.getCode().isArrowKey() )
        {
            switch (e.getCode())
            {
                case DOWN:
                    bY += step;
                    break;

                case UP:
                    bY -= step;
                    break;

                case LEFT:
                    bX -= step;
                    break;

                case RIGHT:
                    bX += step;
                    break;
            }
            path.getElements().add( new LineTo( bX, bY ) );
        }
    } );

    Scene scene = new Scene( myPane, 150, 150 );
    primaryStage.setTitle( "Draw Line with Arrow Keys" );
    primaryStage.setScene( scene );
    primaryStage.show();
    path.requestFocus();
}
```

I am not a fan of providing ready code for homework like questions. But at least it seems you have tried to implement.

Comment: Yeah thanks for that. I had looked up the Path class in my book and read it over. The only tip that was offered regarding the assignment was in each case or when each key is hit to generate a "new line". I was a little puzzled by that. Someone suggested to use polyline and store the points in a list, then use a loop to iterate, but then that would mean you would have a set number off lines to be drawn. In swing , you simply would have had to call the repaint() method. Here, you're drawing the same line based of the beginning x and beginning y coordinates.

Comment: @FlyingFinger1125, this code can easily be converted to "new Line()" version.

Comment: I made some modifications to my code, however, I only get dots as opposed to lines connecting the dots as I hit the arrow keys. I am almost done but it would appear I am overlooking something...